How to prevent NiFi flow from being blocked in conditional case
I have a flow group, its content likes this:
                          +->row_count=0-->LogAttr-->terminate
inport-->RouteOnRowCount--|
                          +->row_count>0-->continue...

However, I observed it is blocked while the condition row_count=0 matched. Relevant configs include: 

the relation "not matched" of RouteOnRowCount processor are set to terminate, relation NoData(${row_count:equals(0)}) set to LogAttr.
Success relation of LogAttr is set to terminate.
the concurrency policy of the group is set to "Single File Per Node"
the outbound policy of the group is set to "Stream When Available"

My question is:

Why it's blocked.
How to let the group terminated when row_count=0.

Why do I add the NoData case but lead it to being terminated? Why don't I just remove this case instead of?
the reason is that I want to add some reporting functions here, now the empty case is just a placeholder.
Addtional material: I have a serialized groups. Dozons of tables ordered(because dependencies exist among some of them) pass through the groups. 
While testing, I observed the whole flow stopped. The reason is that a table is fallen into the NoData case. In theory, the procession of this table is finished, the next table should be dragged into this group to be processed. However, nothing happened, no error reported, the whole flow is like frozen.
And if the flow didn't go along NoData branch, after one table is processed, the flow can start to process the next table normally.
